# 1KR timing chain cover wont come off

Tags: head-gasket, timing-chain, daihatsu

[image: Gap between cover and engine][Cover](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZbMXs.jpg)  I have a Daihatsu Charade with a 1KR engine with a blown head gasket.
I have loosened everything on the timing chain cover but I cant get it off.
It moves a lot but something seems to catch near the crank at the bottom of the cover. Any assistance would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Have you removed the crank pulley? ie does the shaft come through the timing cover? Some pictures would help...

Comment: What year Charade??

Comment: It is a 2007 with a 1KR engine. I am trying to load images. the pulley is off

Comment: Oil pan bolts? Rtv?

Comment: I have removed all the oil pan bolts as well.The cover is completely loose so no rtv problem. (See gap in photo)

Comment: Separate engine from gearbox. Loosen two nuts behind flywheel by removing clutch assembly and flywheel. Take off oil pan. Remove timing chain cover.

Answer (score -1):

You must remove the oil pan (Sump) as the oil pick up is jamming , there for it will not come out